# “Can’t call method ‘state’ on an undefined value”?

Tags: perl

I am new at perl. I am learning from a book, in that one example is there. I am not able to find the problem in that.

```
use 5.010;
greet( 'Fred' );
greet( 'Barney' );
sub greet {
    state $last_person;
    my $name = shift;
    print "Hi $name! ";
    # This is the error line:
    if( defined $last_person ) {   
       print "$last_person is also here!\n";
    } else {
       print "You are the first one here!\n"
    }
    $last_person = $name;
}
```

It gives error like "Can't call method "state" on an undefined value at ch4_3.pl."

Comment: What does `perl -v` say?

Comment: I didn't write the use 5.010. Mine is 5.18.2.

Comment: @Raj — "I didn't write the use 5.010" — So the code you have put in the question is not the same code as that which gives the error message? You removed that use statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the `state` feature is not enabled? Quoting [the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html):

> state variables are enabled only when the use feature "state" pragma is in effect, unless the keyword is written as CORE::state . See also feature. Alternately, include a use v5.10 or later to the current scope.

And as I read in the comments, you didn’t include the `use 5.010` pragma. I think that’s the problem. Without it, my Perl (5.18.2, same as yours) complains of the same error.

Comment: but if we are using the higher version 5.18.2 then do we need to write 5.010?

Comment: @Raj — `use 5.010` means "Turn on all the features that were considered stable in 5.10" (personally I prefer the syntax `use v5.10`) not "Only work for Perl 5.10 and nothing newer".